# Delaying message to RabbitMQ in java w/o DelayedMessage plugin or stopping thread

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I need to delay sending a message to RabbitMQ but am not authorized to use the DelayedMessage plugin and do not want to stop a thread. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You could always just use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and schedule a task that will publish a message with delay. However, if your application crashes/restarts/stops before that happens, the message will never get into RabbitMQ.

Comment: From what I have read, isn't that essentially the same as Thread.sleep()? That is something I was told to avoid.

Comment: It's not. `Thread.sleep` will suspend current thread. `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` is used to execute tasks in future. It won't block anything.